# Is there a way to tell fetch() to not decode percent 2E (%2E) to dot (.) on a URL?

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, fetch-api, urlencode

I'm trying to use `fetch()` with my URL that has `%2E` on it (for example, `/foo/bar/192%2E168%2E1%2E1.json`. When I use `fetch()`, it decodes the `%2E` back to a dot `.` (`/foo/bar/192.168.1.1.json`), and it errors out since my backend counterpart can't find the suitable route for the request (`404` on network tab).

Does anyone have a workaround on this?

Comment: Have you tried `encodeURI` and `encodeComponentURI`?

Comment: So are you saying that the route at the server involves a filename with "%2E" appearing in it? If so, you're going to have to encode the "%" characters too. That's kind-of a bizarre situation however.

Comment: The decoding happens on the server, not in `fetch()` on the client.

Comment: @ControlAltDel yeah that's what I use when encoding the `.` to `%2E`, but on doing `fetch('/foo/bar/192%2E168%2E1%2E1.json')`, it is showing as `fetch('/foo/bar/192.168.1.1.json')` on the networks tab instead of the former. I used `cURL` to simulate the same request and `cURL` works fine if the URL contains `%2E`, but not on the javascript side when `fetch()` is used.

Comment: it seems that `fetch()` decodes the encoded URL (dot to `%2E`) and I am not sure why